# Searching for the closest "stop" elements surrounding a start point

Tags: javascript

This code works but is there a simple / better way to do this?

It starts from a particular point (`starthere`) in the array, looks for first `stop` value to the left of start point, and the first `stop` to the right side.

Basically returns the closest values' positions to a start point both sides. (I'll make this a function.)

```
var arr = ['f','f','stop','stop','f','f','starthere','f','f','f','stop','stop','f','f','f','f'];

var i = arr.indexOf('starthere');
while (i--) {
    if (arr[i] == 'stop') {
        document.write(i + '</br>');
        break;
    }
}

for (var i = arr.indexOf('starthere'); i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 'stop') {
        document.write(i);
        break;
    }

}
```

Returns `3</br>10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overload of `.indexOf` that takes a second parameter indicating the starting location for the search.  That can be used to find the `stop` after `starthere`. Then you can use `.slice` to grab the part of the array before `starthere` with `lastIndexOf` to find the `stop` that comes before:

```
var i = arr.indexOf('starthere');
var stopafter = arr.indexOf('stop', i);
var stopbefore = arr.slice(0, i).lastIndexOf('stop');
document.write(stopbefore + '</br>' + stopafter);
```